# Generating 3d points from GeoTIFF using libgeotiff and proj

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, proj, cartesian

I'm working on a C++ library where I need to ingest several different DEM formats (such as GeoTIFFs, SPC Maplets, and some other internal formats) and convert them to a 3d triangular mesh.  In the past, I've used GDAL for this but for reasons I can't get into right now, I cannot use GDAL itself in this library.

I'm currently able to use [libgeotiff](https://github.com/OSGeo/libgeotiff/tree/671f6d5ddbfb3f8a328dfd1b45047a868fea819e) and [libtiff](https://github.com/libsdl-org/libtiff), and can read use these to read the relevant tags as well as the height data from each pixel.  This works as expected however I now need to convert this grid of heights into a mesh of xyz-coordinates.  (NOTE: if it is relevant, the GeoTIFFs I'm working with are of other planetary bodies, NOT the earth).

After some reading it looks as though the [proj](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/tree/master) library should be capable of doing what I'd want, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it.  (My background is not in cartography and the other formats I had to support, such as SPC Maplets, I had a straight forward mathspecs to follow.  So working with a GeoTIFF and all the possible projections and what not is a bit outside my wheelhouse).

My assumption is that there is something about the GeoTIFF I can read that will allow `proj` can use to convert each pixel into xyz cartesian coordinates...  but I'm not sure what to read or what functions from `proj` I'd want to use.

I know this is a really basic question but I'm hoping someone could give me any advice to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for this advice!  It took me a bit of time but I was able to figure out I could obtain the "GTIF Definition" (`GTIFDefn*`) as well as the Raster dimensions and pixel scale.  From there I can use the function `GTIFProj4ToLatLon()` to obtain the lat/lon coordinates for each pixel.  Presumably that is the correct first step, as now I can simply convert these lat/lon coordinates into cartesian xyz?  (From the documentation I've tried reading, I believe that is the conversion from geodetic to geocentric?)  My concern only concern is if this remains valid for polar stereogrphic maps

Comment: I suppose my confusion is that I found the `GTIFProj4ToLatLong()` function that allows me to go from pixel coordinate to lat/lon.  I don't see any similar function available from `libgeotiff` to go from pixel coordinate to polar stereographic coordinate, which (if I'm understanding what you're suggesting) seems like it would be an intermediate step before converting to cartesian.  If I'm misunderstanding please let me know.  (Some of my data is in cylindrical coordinates so the conversion from pixel to lat/lon feels intuitive as an intermediate step before going to cartesian)

Comment: Any projected coordinate system is cartesian. If your data is in a projected CRS all you need to do is get the coordinates of the upper left corner `ModelTiepointTag` (`ulx`, `uly`) and the height & width of each pixel `ModelPixelScaleTag` (`pw`, `ph`) then you can calculate the x, y for each element (i ,j) of the 2d raster array using row(i) & col(j) e.g (`x = (i * pw) + ulx` and (`y = (j * py) + uly`)

Comment: @user2856 ahh ok.  It looks like I can extract a proj4 string using `GTIFGetProj4Defn()`.  So having the `x` and `y` coordinates it looks like I can simply use `proj_create_crs_to_crs(ctx, proj4str, target_crs, area)` where `proj4str` is from the above function.  I'd just need to figure out the correct `target_crs` string to use.

Comment: I need to convert (for example) from the polar stereographic coordinates to cartesian xyz points